# Nested Joins result in error 400 Bad Request

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When performing multiple nested joins I get an error 400 bad request when using the dataflow service. Using the local pipeline runner works fine. Below is some sample code of what i am trying to achieve:

```
    PipelineOptions pipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(PipelineOptions.class);
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(pipelineOptions);
    Datastore datastore = getDatastore(pipelineOptions, DATASET_ID);

    addData(datastore);

    PCollection<KV<Long, DatastoreV1.Entity>> users = pipeline.apply(DatastoreIO.readFrom(DATASET_ID, makeQueryForKind("Entity1")))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new MakeKVFromParent()));
    PCollection<KV<Long, DatastoreV1.Entity>> locations = pipeline.apply(DatastoreIO.readFrom(DATASET_ID, makeQueryForKind("Entity2")))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new MakeKVFromParent()));
    PCollection<KV<Long, DatastoreV1.Entity>> cars = pipeline.apply(DatastoreIO.readFrom(DATASET_ID, makeQueryForKind("Entity3")))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new MakeKVFromParent()));

    TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity> carsTag = new TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity>();
    PCollection<KV<Long, CoGbkResult>> groupedCars = KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(carsTag, cars)
            .apply(CoGroupByKey.<Long>create());

    TupleTag<CoGbkResult> groupedCarsTag = new TupleTag<CoGbkResult>();
    TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity> locationsTag = new TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity>();
    PCollection<KV<Long, CoGbkResult>> locationData = KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(groupedCarsTag, groupedCars)
            .and(locationsTag, locations)
            .apply(CoGroupByKey.<Long>create());

    //Comment this block of code to remove the bug.
    TupleTag<CoGbkResult> locationDataTag = new TupleTag<CoGbkResult>();
    TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity> usersTag = new TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity>();
    PCollection<KV<Long, CoGbkResult>> userData = KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(locationDataTag, locationData)
            .and(usersTag, users)
            .apply(CoGroupByKey.<Long>create());

    //Do some computation on userData
    pipeline.run();
```

Basically i have a bunch of users. A user can have multiple locations and cars. A Car is always attached to a specific location and user. I want to group the cars by user and location so i know the locations each user has and the cars he has at each location. I do some computation on this data for each user.

A working example demonstrating my problem can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/pieterdem/dataflow-join-bug).

The error occurs when the job is submitted. The submitted job file can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/pieterdem/dataflow-join-bug/src/61f687b39b1241f22da8cb8d1b4df82f228baf69/job.json?at=master)

The job runs fine when the last join is removed. Does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, and also for the great example code! We've tracked down an issue in the service and are working on fixing it. While we work on fixing this, you can avoid the issue by not re-using the `CoGroupByKeyResult` as an input to a `CoGroupByKey`.

Specifically, in this case doing the following will reduce the number of `CoGroupByKey` operations, make it easier to get your data out, and also avoids using the `CoGroupByKeyResult` as an input to `CoGroupByKey`:

```
TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity> carsTag = new TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity>();
TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity> locationsTag = new TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity>();
TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity> usersTag = new TupleTag<DatastoreV1.Entity>();

PCollection<KV<Long, CoGbkResult>> usersCars = KeyedPCollectionTuple
    .of(carsTag, cars)
    .and(locationsTag, locations)
    .and(usersTag, users)
    .apply(CoGroupByKey.<Long>create());
```

With the above it is now easier to access parts of the `CoGbkResult` too. For example:

```
// Before (with nested CoGroupByKey)
originalResult.getOnly(locationDataTag).getOnly(groupedCarsTag).getAll(usersTag);

// After (with a single CoGroupByKey)
newResult.getAll(usersTag);
```